# Symfony2 embed form with file into another form

Tags: forms, file, symfony

I have an Item entity and an Image entity, which a OneToOne relation between them.
I also have an ItemType and ImageType forms.
Until now when I have a situation like this one I use the two forms separately (rendering them into a single html form) and setting the relation inside the controller or the form handler. Is there a -symfony- way to embed the ImageType form into the ItemType one?
A little code maybe can help.
Item:

```
namespace Company\ItemBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use NewZaarly\ImageBundle\Entity\Image;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @var \NewZaarly\ImageBundle\Entity\ImageItem
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="NewZaarly\ImageBundle\Entity\ImageItem", mappedBy="item", cascade={"persist", "merge", "remove"})
     */
    private $image;

    //other fields. Setters and getters
}
```

Image:

```
<?php

namespace Company\ImageBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize = "2M", mimeTypes = {"image/png", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"})
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

   /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="image", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $image;

    //other fields, setter and getters
}
```

ImageType

```
<?php

namespace Company\ImageBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('file', 'file', array('required' => true));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'image';
    }
}
```

And the ItemType form

```
<?php

namespace Company\ItemBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Company\ImageBundle\Form\Type\ImageType;

class ItemType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('title', 'text');
        $builder->add('image', new ImageType()); // <-- this is what I'd like to do
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Company\ItemBundle\Entity\Item');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Company\ItemBundle\Entity\Item'));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'item';
    }

}
```

Doing it like this I get an error when binding the request because the image is an array an not an Image object, what is expected in the setImage method in the Item class.
My handle function is pretty simple:

```
public function handle(FormInterface $form, Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $item = $form->getData();
            $this->itemManager->saveItem($item);

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Any idea? I don't like the first way I specified for doing it.

Comment: Have you seen Symfony docs about the subject? [here](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/form_collections.html)

Comment: Of course I did, and I have several embed forms, but I have problem with this one which has a file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved by adding data_class to embedded field, in my case I define the upload form as service (app_document_upload)

```
//Document Class

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
    //other fields here ...
    ->add('image', 'app_document_upload', array(
            'data_class' => 'App\DocumentBundle\Entity\Document'
        ))
}
```